# Missing emergency sos on iPhone 5 (iOS 10.2)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.2. The recent update included a setting which allowed users in India to make emergency calls by clicking the sleep/wake button five times. I seem to be missing that setting completely. My question is:

1. Is it a build issue or a device issue?
2. Is it not available for the iPhone 5?

[image]

[image]

I have verified the countries this setting is available in. It clearly states India in them.

Further, are there any solutions you can suggest which could help me resolve this issue?
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I read on an Apple news site, I don't remember which one, that the government isn't ready yet so Apple hasn't activated it.  If I remember or find the site again, I'll update my comment.

Comment: @fsb I have a dozen friends who have the setting working for them

Comment: If they're all on the same iPhone and iOS version as you, then I guess what I read was old or out of date, sorry.  If you think you should have it but don't, I suggest you contact Apple Support to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your phone manufactured in India, or manufactured elsewhere and brought in?  Not sure why it makes a difference, but I read somewhere that it is only available on iPhones made in India.

Comment: I had got it exchanged for a new phone under their replacement scheme. But I think you are right, it's only available if your phone is manufactured for India (i.e. Model number ends in HN/A)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are in one of the suppoerted countries:

> Australia, Belgium, Brazil, Canada, China, France, Hong Kong, India, Italy, Japan, Russia, Spain, the United Kingdom, and the United States

or not.

Comment: I reside in India

Comment: You devices region and (and maybe App Store settings)  are set to India also?

Comment: Yes. Both set to India

Comment: Don't know than sorry. I do not have the feature (Germany). Afaics, it should be available in India since 1.1.2017.

Comment: That's what is puzzling me. I believe there is a law which requires this setting to be on all phones in India. So I'm not sure what is wrong here

Comment: Danke für die hilfe :)

Comment: Hahaha . Gerne!